# Optional quadratic variation and predictable quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, quadratic-variation

What's the difference between optional quadratic variation (which sometimes is denoted by $
[M]$) and predictable quadratic variation (i.e $\ < M > $) of a stochastic process?

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/902886/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi here are my two cents :

$<>$ is the predictable compensator of $[]$ process ( so the difference of both is a local martingale).

The difference is best illustrated by examining a Poisson process of intensity $\lambda$.

Then the $[N]_t=\sum_{s\le t}(\Delta N_s)^2=\sum_{s\le t}(\Delta N_s)=N_t$ this process is not predictable as its jumps are inaccessible.

But $<N>_t=\lambda.t$ (comes from standard calculations) this process is predictable as it is deterministic.

And finally $[N]_t-<N>_t=N_t -\lambda.t$ is a (local) martingale.

You should take a look at [George Lowther fantastic Blog "almost sure"](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/)

Best regards

Comment: Why is $\sum_{s\le t}(\Delta N_s)^2=\sum_{s\le t}(\Delta N_s)$?

Comment: Because Poisson process jump sizes are equal to 1.