# The meaning of $d\langle Z(t,x),Z(t,y)\rangle =c(x,y)\,dt$ where $Z$ is a random field

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

This question is influenced by [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2646029?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) paper.

Consider a random field $Z(t,x)$ with a correlation structure given by

$$d\langle Z(t,x),Z(t,y)\rangle =c(x,y)\,dt.$$

For example, a choice for the correlation function can be $c(x,y)=ae^{-k|x-y|}.$

My question is, what is the meaning of the correlation structure $d\langle Z(t,x),Z(t,y)\rangle=c(x,y)\,dt$? Is $c(x,y)$ an instantaneous correlation between the random variables $Z(t,x)$ and $Z(t,y)$?. How (or why) is the cross-variation $\langle Z(t,x),Z(t,y)\rangle$ related to the correlation structure? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: On proper typesetting:$$
\begin{align}
\text{wrong: }\qquad & d<Z(t,x),Z(t,y)>=c(x,y)dt \\ {} \\
\text{right: }\qquad & d\langle Z(t,x),Z(t,y)\rangle =c(x,y)\,dt
\end{align}
$$
(I've edited accordingly.)

Comment: According to the papar,the identity is the very definition of the “correlation” $c$ .

Comment: It means that $Z(t,x)Z(t,y)-c(x,y)t$ is a (local) martingale.

Comment: It's the sharp bracket/compensator: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902886/angle-bracket-and-sharp-bracket-for-discontinuous-processes